# How to find if user input is already in CSV database?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am working on a project where a user inputs a time (ex. 600) and the program looks through the CSV file to see if the users time is available and if the time is not available to ask the user to try another time.

I run it through a for loop but it runs through every line and says the time is found but it loops not found till it finds the time.

```py
def main():
    import csv

# Asks user for requested into
    answer = input("What time would you like to look for: ")

    # Opens CSV
    with open("sun_data.csv") as csvfile:
        # Extracts data from the file
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)

        for column in readCSV:
            for x in column:
                if x == answer:
                    print("found")
                else:
                    print("Time not available try again.")

    # Close input file
    csvfile.close()


main()
```

loops:
Time not available try again.
Time not available try again.
found
Time not available try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing at the end instead of through the whole for loop.

```
    with open("sun_data.csv") as csvfile:
        # Extracts data from the file
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
        found = FALSE
        for column in readCSV:
            for x in column:
                if x == answer:
                    found = TRUE
        if(found):
            print("Found")
        else:
            print("Time not available, try again")
    main()
```

Comment: When used "with open" the csvfile will close automatically.  The line csvfile.close () is not needed.